# Import file error "missing name after . operator" in Titanium

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

when i import my file in Titanium, i have a red cross mark in front of my line showing

```
missing name after . operator
```

my code goes like this way

```
Ti.App.import('win1.js');
Ti.App.import('win2.js');

// Create tabgroup and tabs
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: win1.title,
    window: win1
});
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: win2.title,
    window: win2
});
tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
tabGroup.addTab(tab2);
tabGroup.open({});
```

in first and second line i have such type of error though i have created those two files....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Ti.include('relative-path-for-file-to-include.js');
```

or

```
Titanium.include('relative-path-for-file-to-include.js');
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

i found this way of including other files in titanium.... and it worked for me.

```
Titanium.include("page1.js");
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be:

`#include "win1.js";`

Comment: its not working  # sign shows error  "Multiple markers at this line" But i found solution.. go through my answer below..